# Is it possible to get value of current id from web api in angular as soon as the new data is posted?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am generating an invoice having many sales transactions. Initially a customer whose status is false and have many transaction is selected and a invoice is generated. Now while the invoice is generated I want those status to be true and all the selected transactions to be assigned with newly generated invoice.

I am able to generated invoice based on the selected transaction. But now I am not able to assign that invoice Id to those transactions.

It will be easy if I could get the current generated invoice Id. Can anyone help me?

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.service.getSalesTransaction(this.id).subscribe((singleData: any) => {

    this.service.getAllSalesTransactions().subscribe((data: any) => {
      data.forEach(element => {
        if (singleData.CustomerName === element.CustomerName 
            && element.Status === false) {
          //Pushing valid object into an array
          this.salesTransaction.push(element);

          //Calculating Sub Total
          this.subTotal = this.salesTransaction.reduce((acc, val) => acc+=val.Total, 0);
          console.log(this.subTotal);

          //Calculating Tax based on the amount
          if (this.subTotal <= 500) {
            this.tax = (10 / 100) * this.subTotal;
            console.log(this.tax);
          } else {
            this.tax = (5 / 100) * this.subTotal;
            console.log(this.tax);
          }
        }
      });

      //Preparing data for invoice database
      this.invoiceData.Tax = Math.round(this.tax);

      //Creating new Invoice
      this.serviceInvoice.createInvoice(this.invoiceData).subscribe((dataInvoice) => {
        console.log('Invoice -', dataInvoice);
        console.log(this.invoiceData);
      });
    });
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will something like this not work ?

```
var invoice = CreateInvoice(invoice); //invoice with transactions

if(invoice.Id!=default(int)) { //checking if resource is created

return Ok(invoice);

}
```

On angular side:

grab the Observable of Invoice and get id

/*********************My Webp APi COde*******************/

```
 public IHttpActionResult PostInvoice([FromBody] Invoice invoice){

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

        try
        {
            using (var context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                context.Invoices.Add(invoice);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok("Sales Transaction was created!" + invoice.InvoiceId);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, the above code does not work for me.  My Wep Api code for post is mentioned above.

Comment: how to grab invoice with observable?

Comment: what did you write inside createInvoice () method on angular side ?

Answer (score 1):

This will happen because of this service call behaves **Asynchronously**, sometimes if you use the **Synchronous** way, will solve this issue

[angular-guide](https://angular.io/guide/comparing-observables)

Comment: I do not Have Proper Example For that ,i think this will help [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/q1)